# Objective c save image to gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, writetofile

I manipulated some pixels in image and now when i open the image in app, a message appears but problem is that i saved it to my document directory. I want to allow someone to share this photo. If i save the image below, the image data changes.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

If i save the image to app documents, i can't pick it with imagepicker.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",self.imageName.text]];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath
                                                     atomically:YES];
```

So my question is that can i save image to gallery with a custom name or can i save image to gallery with path ?

Answer (score 2):

You can save image to the gallery by name

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:"someImage.png"];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: [UIImage imageNamed:"someImage.png"] loads image.

Comment: What do u mean by loads image?

Comment: This code loads image from assets. I didn't understand how it changes the name?

Comment: btw UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil); changes images data

Comment: O i see. U mean that after saving, its name is changes. Maybe conflict with other file with the same name. Btw, u can refer this link for this method [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1619125-uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum?language=objc)